# Django Channels Postgres InterfaceError: connection already closed

Tags: django, postgresql, pytest, python-asyncio, django-channels

I can't seem to wrap my head around the issue here. I'm writing tests for my Channel Consumers following the [description in the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html). I'd normally use the Django default unittest but since Channels requires using pytest, I'm using it but will still like to maintain the class structure of writing tests.

I had issues with writing the setup method similar to unittest which I would use to initialize the test attributes. I tried [method fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html?highlight=setup_class#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown), class fixtures using [autouse=true](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids), but none of them seemed to work as I couldn't access the instance attributes in the test methods. Finally I just decided to write the `set_up` instance method and manually call it for each class. This is what I have so far:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestChatConsumer(object):

    @database_sync_to_async
    def set_up(self):

        self.user = UserFactory()
        self.api_client = APIClientFactory()
        self.token = TokenFactory(user=self.user)

        self.credentials = {
            'AUTHORIZATION': self.token.key,
            ...
        }

        self.credentials_params = '&'.join(['{}={}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.credentials.items()])
        self.authless_endpoint = '/api/v1/ws/'
        self.endpoint = self.authless_endpoint + '?' + self.credentials_params

    async def test_connect_without_credentials(self):
        await self.set_up()
        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application, self.authless_endpoint)
        connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
        assert not connected

    async def test_connect_with_credentials(self):
        await self.set_up()
        communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(application, self.endpoint)
        connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
        assert connected
```

The issue is that I keep getting `psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed` when my consumer tries to access the database in it's code inside the `connect` method. It uses `database_sync_to_async` and works pretty well when I'm manually testing it.

Specifically, the line in the `connect` method that raises the error looks like this:

```
await database_sync_to_async(user.inbox.increment_connections)().
```

Not sure what exactly the issue is as `database_sync_to_async` should properly clean up old connections so that new ones can be properly created.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently I was looking at the wrong place. The issue was on this line:

`await database_sync_to_async(user.inbox.increment_connections)()`.

`inbox` is a related manager so it tries to fetch it before the actual `database_sync_to_async` and it fails as it requires a db call.

I tried this `await database_sync_to_async(user).inbox.increment_connections()` and it didn't work since it wraps a method, not an attribute so what I ended up doing was to use `prefetch_related` to get the `inbox` during the authentication. In that way `user.inbox` no longer requires a db call and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still figuring out how to fix issue like `connection already closed`. Weird that it is not described anywhere (nor docs or Google).

Just replace this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
```

with this

```py
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
```

and for your TestCases class make change accordingly:

```py
class WebsocketsTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    <YOUR TESTS ARE HERE>
```

So all tests will be executed in one transaction without closing the DB connection  in it.

Cheers!