# pytest-mocks and declaring a class level fixture

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm having trouble with pytest-mock and mocking open.

The code I wish to test looks like:

```py
import re
import os

def get_uid():
    regex = re.compile('Serial\s+:\s*(\w+)')
    uid = "NOT_DEFINED"
    exists = os.path.isfile('/proc/cpuinfo')
    if exists:
        with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as file:
            cpu_details = file.read()
            uid = regex.search(cpu_details).group(1)
    return uid
```

So the test file is:

```py
import os
import pytest

from cpu_info import uid

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mocker")
class TestCPUInfo(object):
    def test_no_proc_cpuinfo_file(self):
        mocker.patch(os.path.isfile).return_value(False)
        result = uid.get_uid()
        assert result == "NOT_FOUND"

    def test_no_cpu_info_in_file(self):
        file_data = """
Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a020d3
        """
        mocker.patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open(read_data=file_data))
        result = uid.get_uid()
        assert result == "NOT_DEFINED"

    def test_cpu_info(self):
        file_data = """
Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a020d3
Serial      : 00000000e54cf3fa
        """
        mocker.patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open(read_data=file_data))
        result = uid.get_uid()
        assert result == "00000000e54cf3fa"
```

The test run gives:

```
pytest
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-4.4.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /home/robertpostill/software/gateway
plugins: mock-1.10.4
collected 3 items

cpu_info/test_cpu_info.py FFF                                                                [100%]

============================================= FAILURES =============================================
______________________________ TestCPUInfo.test_no_proc_cpuingo_file _______________________________

self = <test_cpu_info.TestCPUInfo object at 0x75e6eaf0>

    def test_no_proc_cpuingo_file(self):
>       mocker.patch(os.path.isfile).return_value(False)
E       NameError: name 'mocker' is not defined

cpu_info/test_cpu_info.py:9: NameError
___________________________________ TestCPUInfo.test_no_cpu_info ___________________________________

self = <test_cpu_info.TestCPUInfo object at 0x75e69d70>

        def test_no_cpu_info(self):
            file_data = """
    Hardware    : BCM2835
    Revision    : a020d3
            """
>           mocker.patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open(read_data=file_data))
E           NameError: name 'mocker' is not defined

cpu_info/test_cpu_info.py:18: NameError
____________________________________ TestCPUInfo.test_cpu_info _____________________________________

self = <test_cpu_info.TestCPUInfo object at 0x75e694f0>

        def test_cpu_info(self):
            file_data = """
    Hardware    : BCM2835
    Revision    : a020d3
    Serial      : 00000000e54cf3fa
            """
>           mocker.patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open(read_data=file_data))
E           NameError: name 'mocker' is not defined

cpu_info/test_cpu_info.py:28: NameError
===================================== 3 failed in 0.36 seconds =====================================
```

I think I've declared the mocker fixture correctly but it would seem not...  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mark.usefixtures` will only ensure the mentioned fixtures will execute; it will not load `mocker` in the global namespace. In general, you don't access fixture return value like that - include fixture name in the args list, e.g. `def test_no_proc_cpuinfo_file(self, mocker): ...`. `pytest` will replace these args with correct fixture values at runtime.

Comment: I'm totally open to the idea that I'm doing this wrong.  I just seem to be going round in circles of blog posts that don't provide any real illumination as to how I should go about testing this with mocks.

Comment: There is a decent answer below, is there a reason for you not to accept that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are not that many issues with mock usage in your tests. In fact, there are only two:

#### Accessing `mocker` fixture

If you need to access the return value of a fixture, include its name in the test function arguments, for example:

```
class TestCPUInfo:
    def test_no_proc_cpuinfo_file(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch(...)
```

`pytest` will automatically map the test argument value to fixture value when running the tests.

#### Using `mocker.patch`

`mocker.patch` is just a shim to [`unittest.mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch), nothing more; it's there merely for convenience so that you don't have to import `unittest.mock.patch` everywhere. This means that `mocker.patch` has the same signature as `unittest.mock.patch` and you can always consult the stdlib's docs when in doubt of using it correctly.

In you case, `mocker.patch(os.path.isfile).return_value(False)` is not a correct usage of `patch` method. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

> *target* should be a string in the form `'package.module.ClassName'`.
>
> ...
>
> `patch()` takes arbitrary keyword arguments. These will be passed to the `Mock` (or `new_callable`) on construction.

This means that the line

```
mocker.patch(os.path.isfile).return_value(False)
```

should be

```
mocker.patch('os.path.isfile', return_value=False)
```

#### Discrepancies between tested behaviour and real implementation logic

All that is left now are errors that have something to do with your implementation; you have to either adapt the tests to test the correct behaviour or fix the implementation errors.

Examples:

```
assert result == "NOT_FOUND"
```

will always raise because `"NOT_FOUND"` isn't even present in the code.

```
assert result == "NOT_DEFINED"
```

will always raise because `uid = "NOT_DEFINED"` will always be overwritten with regex search result and thus never returned.

#### Working example

Assuming your tests are the single source of truth, I fixed two errors with mock usage described above and adapted the implementation of `get_uid()` to make the tests pass:

```
import os
import re

def get_uid():
    regex = re.compile(r'Serial\s+:\s*(\w+)')
    exists = os.path.isfile('/proc/cpuinfo')
    if not exists:
        return 'NOT_FOUND'
    with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as file:
        cpu_details = file.read()
        match = regex.search(cpu_details)
        if match is None:
            return 'NOT_DEFINED'
        return match.group(1)
```

Tests:

```
import pytest
import uid


class TestCPUInfo:

    def test_no_proc_cpuinfo_file(self, mocker):
        mocker.patch('os.path.isfile', return_value=False)
        result = uid.get_uid()
        assert result == "NOT_FOUND"

    def test_no_cpu_info_in_file(self, mocker):
        file_data = """
Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a020d3
        """
    mocker.patch('builtins.open', mocker.mock_open(read_data=file_data))
        result = uid.get_uid()
        assert result == "NOT_DEFINED"

    def test_cpu_info(self, mocker):
        file_data = """
Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a020d3
Serial      : 00000000e54cf3fa
        """
    mocker.patch('builtins.open', mocker.mock_open(read_data=file_data))
        result = uid.get_uid()
        assert result == "00000000e54cf3fa"
```

Note that I'm using Python 3, so I can't patch `__builtin__` and resort to patching `builtins`; aside from that, the code should be identical to Python 2 variant. Also, since `mocker` is used anyway, I used `mocker.mock_open`, thus saving me the additional import of `unittest.mock.mock_open`.

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer.  Definitely leaves me believing that there's no sane reason that `mocker` is missing as a positional argument  when `_callTestMethod(self, method)` attempts to call my `test_foo(self, mocker)` method.  Too bad it's complaining about the absence of `mocker` anyway :/

Comment: As a follow-up, Test classes derived from `TestCase` with member tests don't really support fixtures like this needs.  Deriving from `object` instead is suggested.  Also see https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock/issues/174

Comment: @interestedparty333 sorry for the late reply, didn't see your comments right away. Yeah, `pytest` features almost aren't supported with `unittest`-style tests; it is possiblt to inject fixtures via an autouse fixture (see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135020/2650249)), but no fixtures as test method args.

Comment: @interestedparty333 I see there's an example of injecting fixtures in the linked GH issue already, disregard my comment.