# How to use fixture in pytest TestClass

Tags: python, pytest

I am unable to use a pytest fixture in a class-based test. My code looks like the following.

main.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import inspect

import pytest


class MyPlugin:

    __name__ = 'my_plugin'

    def pytest_pycollect_makeitem(self, collector, name, obj):
        items = []
        if ((inspect.isfunction(obj) or inspect.ismethod(obj))
                and (name.startswith("test_") or name.endswith("_test"))):

            items.append(pytest.Function.from_parent(collector, name=name))

        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            items.append(pytest.Class.from_parent(collector, name=name))

        return items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(["test.py", "-s"], plugins=[MyPlugin()])
    print("------------------------------")
    pytest.main(["test.py", "-s"])
```

test.py

```py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    print(f"hello")


class TestClass:
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_fixture")
    def test_in_class_with_decorator(self):
        assert True

    def test_in_class(self, my_fixture):
        assert True


def test_out_class(my_fixture):
    assert True
```

when running the code as `./main.py` I am getting the error as

```
FAILED test.py::TestClass::test_in_class - TypeError: TestClass.test_in_class() missing 1 required positional argument: 'my_fixture'
```

The error happens when I am using the plugin(MyPlugin). What needs to be changed in the plugin for a class-based test to access the fixture as a test method parameter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest fixture for a class through self not as method argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132703/pytest-fixture-for-a-class-through-self-not-as-method-argument)